# Reverse for 'fobi.dashboard' not found. 'fobi.dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-templates

Everything was working fine when i have added fobi in my project but somehow while i have added namespace in my url it start giving me the error like below.

Main urls.py

```
re_path(r'^formbuilders/', include('apps.form_builders.urls'),),
```

Form_builders urls.py

```
url(_(r'^$'), view=dashboard, name='fobi.dashboard'),
```

Template

```
{% url 'fobi.dashboard' as fobi_dashboard_url %}
```

Reverse for 'fobi.dashboard' not found. 'fobi.dashboard' is not a valid view function or pattern name.

I have visited many site but did not received any quick fix.

Could you please help me out to fix this issue?

Comment: Did you define a namespace?

Comment: I have not added namespace with this url